# Multiple WHERE in SELECT

Tags: sql, group-by, count, pivot

I need to create two columns, "Andamento" and "Concluido" and each one will have a WHERE that pulls from the "Status" column the options: 'Concluído' and 'Em Progresso'

```
SELECT 
    date_format(Solicitacao, '%m/%Y') AS Mes, 
    COUNT(Status) AS Andamento WHERE Status = 'Em Andamento', 
    COUNT(Status) AS Concluido WHERE Status = 'Concluído' 
FROM demandas_portal 
GROUP BY Mes, Status
```

You should return this to me here

[image]

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: is this MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want conditional aggregation.

Some databases support the standard `filter` syntax, which is in the spirit of your attempt:

```
select 
    date_format(solicitacao, '%m/%Y') as Mes, 
    count(*) filter(where status = 'Em Andamento') as Andamento,
    count(*) filter(where status = 'Em Concluído') as Concluido
from demandas_portal 
where status in ('Em Andamento', 'Em Concluído')    -- if needed
group by Mes
```

But MySQL, which you might be using, doesn't. Instead, you can do:

```
select 
    date_format(solicitacao, '%m/%Y') as Mes, 
    sum(status = 'Em Andamento') as Andamento,
    sum(status = 'Em Concluído') as Concluido
from demandas_portal 
where status in ('Em Andamento', 'Em Concluído')    -- if needed
group by Mes
```